# Correct using gzip with named pipes

Tags: linux, gzip, tar, named-pipes

I am trying to create a named pipe which can take a directory as an input and put it into an tar.gz archive
What I tried to do was something like this:

```
mkfifo channel
gzip -9 -c < channel > out.tar.gz
```

But it only accepts text data like

```
cat myfile > channel
```

Is there any way I could pass directory into this pipe or modify it so it could take it as an argument? 
Thank you.

Comment: And this is the magic of `tar` - take a directory and output text that represents files and directories and all attributes of them with the content.

Comment: What @KamilCuk said; or `cpio` ...

Comment: @KamilCuk Thank you a lot, it moved me towards the solution! I've published it below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer describes a named pipe which *compresses* any input it gets.  If you pipe in an uncompressed archive of a directory (a `.tar`) in, it will compress this into a compressed archive (a `.tgz`).

Also, any other string as input would be compressed using this:

```
$ echo "hello world" > channel
$ zcat out.tar.gz
```

This would print `hello world` and the file `out.tar.gz` would not be a proper `.tgz` (or `.tar.gz` which is just the longer form).

Your original question sounded more like you would like to have a *directory* as input (not already an archive of it).  This could mean the path to the directory.  You could achieve this so:

```
read dirpath < channel; tar cfz out.tgz "$dirpath"
```

This will sleep until something can be read from the pipe.

And in another shell you could provide the directory to archive:

```
echo path/to/directory > channel
```

Then the first shell will start working, compress the named directory and produce the `out.tgz` file.

Answer (score 2):

The solution was as simple as

```
tar cf - MyDirectory/ > channel
```

The channel I used was the same.